# problem when making call interconnection using the plivo api

Tags: node.js, express, plivo

I am currently working with the plivo api to build an ivr, however, I have used all the recommendations given by the documentation and so far I can not establish a successful connection within the conference calls in the application, below I attach the code that is involved in the conference function.
getDialConnecting(numberFrom, numberTo, route){
let ivr = new Ivr();

```
let client = ivr.getClient();

client.calls.create(
  `${numberFrom}`,
  `${numberTo}`,
  `${process.env.HOST}${route}`,
  {
    answerMethod: "POST"
  },
).then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
}, function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

this function is called each time I make a conference call and enter the following parameters
I am currently working with the plivo api to build an ivr, however, I have used all the recommendations given by the documentation and so far I can not establish a successful connection within the conference calls in the application, below I attach the code that is involved in the conference function.

```
call.getDialConnecting(`${incomingNumber}`, `${incomingNumberTransmitter}`, 'conference');
```

in addition this is the path that is performing the handling of the function that accepts the call

```
const ivrGetConference = route.post('/voice/conference', call.callRequestConfirmed);
```

Answer (score 1):

My name is Mohammed Huzaif, and I work at Plivo as a Product Evangelist.

From the information shared, I'm unable to determine the error you may have received on your end or the documents utilised.

However, you can follow the below steps to build an IVR.

- First, we'll create our IVR, To do so, follow the directions in this [documentation](https://www.plivo.com/docs/voice/use-cases/ivr/node#xml-create-a-express-server-to-implement-phone-system-ivr).
- Once the IVR system is developed, we will make a call to the destination number by using the URL generated in above step.
  To make a call, use the below code.

**Note:** Replace the placeholders "**from**": with the caller_id, "**to**": Destination number, and "**answer_url**": the url generated in above step.

```
    var plivo = require('plivo'); 
    (function main() {
    'use strict';
    var client = new plivo.Client("<auth_id>","<auth_token>"); // https://console.plivo.com/dashboard/
    client.calls.create(
        "+14151234567", // from
        "+15671234567", // to
        "https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.plivo.com/answer.xml", // answer url
        {
            answerMethod: "POST",
        },
    ).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });})();
```

In case, if you still need any assistance, feel free to reach out to our [support-team](https://support.plivo.com/hc/en-us).